# How to calculate daily percentage over month on month volume?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to sum the volume based on month and year for certain records in the given data and then for the given month I am trying to calculate the daily percentage arrival in power bi

for the record `Person A,1/1/2018,Project,100,1` it should be 100/220

Below is the example data:

```
Resource Name,Month,RecordType,Actual,Flag
Person A,1/1/2018,Project,100,1
Person A,1/2/2018,Support,40,1
Person A,1/3/2018,Training,50,1
Person A,1/4/2018,Unavailable,30,1
Person A,2/1/2018,Project,80,1
Person A,2/2/2018,Support,50,1
Person A,2/3/2018,Training,20,1
Person A,2/4/2018,Unavailable,50,1
Person A,3/1/2018,Project,150,1
Person A,3/2/2018,Support,10,1
Person A,3/3/2018,Training,20,1
Person A,3/4/2018,Unavailable,20,1
Person B,1/1/2018,Project,50,0
Person B,1/1/2018,Support,100,0
Person B,1/1/2018,Training,45,0
Person B,1/1/2018,Unavailable,5,0
Person B,2/1/2018,Project,90,0
Person B,2/1/2018,Support,80,0
Person B,2/1/2018,Training,10,0
Person B,2/1/2018,Unavailable,20,0
Person B,3/1/2018,Project,180,0
Person B,3/1/2018,Support,5,0
Person B,3/1/2018,Training,10,0
Person B,3/1/2018,Unavailable,5,0
```

Tried below but getting error

```
  Daily_percentage1 = CALCULATE(data1[Actual])/CALCULATE(SUM(data1[Actual]),FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(data1,data1[Month].[Month],data1[Month].[Year]),data1[Flag]=1))
```

Expedted Output

```
Resource Name,RecordType,Flag,Month,Actual,Daily_percentage1
Person A,Project,1,1/1/2018 0:00,100,0.454545455
Person A,Support,1,1/2/2018 0:00,40,0.181818182
Person A,Training,1,1/3/2018 0:00,50,0.227272727
Person A,Unavailable,1,1/4/2018 0:00,30,0.136363636
Person A,Project,1,2/1/2018 0:00,80,0.4
Person A,Support,1,2/2/2018 0:00,50,0.25
Person A,Training,1,2/3/2018 0:00,20,0.1
Person A,Unavailable,1,2/4/2018 0:00,50,0.25
Person A,Project,1,3/1/2018 0:00,150,0.75
Person A,Support,1,3/2/2018 0:00,10,0.05
Person A,Training,1,3/3/2018 0:00,20,0.1
Person A,Unavailable,1,3/4/2018 0:00,20,0.1
Person B,Project,0,1/1/2018 0:00,50,
Person B,Support,0,1/1/2018 0:00,100,
Person B,Training,0,1/1/2018 0:00,45,
Person B,Unavailable,0,1/1/2018 0:00,5,
Person B,Project,0,2/1/2018 0:00,90,
Person B,Support,0,2/1/2018 0:00,80,
Person B,Training,0,2/1/2018 0:00,10,
Person B,Unavailable,0,2/1/2018 0:00,20,
Person B,Project,0,3/1/2018 0:00,180,
Person B,Support,0,3/1/2018 0:00,5,
Person B,Training,0,3/1/2018 0:00,10,
Person B,Unavailable,0,3/1/2018 0:00,5,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone has their own choice, I would like to handle this in one measure rather having 2 separate measures.

```
Total_Percentage = 
VAR TotalPerMonth =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( data1[Actual] ),
        FILTER ( data1, data1[Month].[Month] = EARLIER ( data1[Month].[Month] ) ),
        FILTER ( data1, data1[Month].[Year] = EARLIER ( data1[Month].[Year] ) ),
        FILTER ( data1, data1[Flag] = 1 )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( data1[actual], TotalPerMonth, 0 )
// taking care of divide by zero error
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for my own question if anyone have better answer let me know
I created two columns

```
TotalPerMonth =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( data1[Actual] ),
    FILTER ( data1, data1[Month].[Month] = EARLIER ( data1[Month].[Month] ) ),
    FILTER ( data1, data1[Month].[Year] = EARLIER ( data1[Month].[Year] ) ),
    FILTER ( data1, data1[Flag] = 1 )
)

Total_percentage =
100 * ( data1[Actual] / data1[TotalPerMonth] )
```