# Trying to Calculate daily percentage based on Filter and ALLEXCEPT

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the below question which I asked earlier but along with that I want to filter further along with other columns apart from month and year I want to add Resource Name,RecordType

[How to calculate daily percentage over month on month volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55656831/how-to-calculate-daily-percentage-over-month-on-month-volume/55657718#55657718)

Below I tried to add `allexcept` which is not working

```
Total_Percentage = 
VAR TotalPerMonth =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( data1[Actual] ),
        FILTER ( data1, data1[Month].[Month] = EARLIER ( data1[Month].[Month] ) ),
        FILTER ( data1, data1[Month].[Year] = EARLIER ( data1[Month].[Year] ) ),
        ALLEXCEPT(data1,data[RecordType],data1[Resource Name]),
                FILTER ( data1, data1[Flag] = 1 )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( data1[actual], TotalPerMonth, 0 )
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not working"? Are you getting an error message? Unexpected results?

Comment: I am getting the same output as I am getting in the above question which I previously asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bit more optimized:

```
Total_Percentage =
VAR TotalPerMonth =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( data1[Actual] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLEXCEPT ( data1, data[RecordType], data1[Resource Name] ),
            data1[Month].[Month] = EARLIER ( data1[Month].[Month] ) &&
            data1[Month].[Year] = EARLIER ( data1[Month].[Year] ) &&
            data1[Flag] = 1
        )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( data1[actual], TotalPerMonth, 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for me. If you have any optimized please let me know

```
Total_Percentage = 
VAR TotalPerMonth =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( data1[Actual] ),
        FILTER ( data1, data1[Month].[Month] = EARLIER ( data1[Month].[Month] ) ),
        FILTER ( data1, data1[Month].[Year] = EARLIER ( data1[Month].[Year] ) ),
        FILTER(ALL('data1'),[Resource Name]=EARLIER('data1'[Resource Name])),
        FILTER(ALL('data1'),[RecordType]=EARLIER('data1'[RecordType])),
        FILTER ( data1, data1[Flag] = 1 )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( data1[actual], TotalPerMonth, 0 )
```